# Splitting a string at at every element of a specified vector

Tags: r, string

I am wrestling with a problem for which I was sure there was an easy solution, but I haven't been able to find it. Thanks for any help.

I'm trying to split a string of text, whenever an element of a separate vector occurs. Something like the following:

```
fruits<-c("APPLE","BANANA","ORANGE")
string<-("This is a list of fruits and their properties. 
         APPLE This is a red fruit, typically very SWEET! 
         BANANA This is a yellow fruit, also sweet! 
         ORANGE This is an orange fruit and also, yes, sweet")
```

My desired output is a list/vector of 4 elements, each of which contains the splits of the strings before/after any of the elements of 'fruits' occurs. So, something like:

```
c("This is a list of fruits and their properties",
"APPLE This is a red fruit, typically very SWEET!",
"BANANA This is a yellow fruit, also sweet!,
"ORANGE This is an orange fruit and also, yes, sweet")
```

I have tried

```
strsplit(string,split=fruits)
```

As well as a couple of other things, but with no success. What I'm actually trying to do is split a .pdf codebook that I've converted into .txt by a list of words (countries), that correspond to sections of the codebook.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "I don't really want to think about regex" way is do do something like:

```
strsplit(gsub(sprintf('(%s)', paste(fruits, collapse = "|")), 
              "MYSPLIT\\1", string), 
         "MYSPLIT", TRUE)[[1]]
# [1] "This is a list of fruits and their properties. \n         "  
# [2] "APPLE This is a red fruit, typically very SWEET! \n         "
# [3] "BANANA This is a yellow fruit, also sweet! \n         "      
# [4] "ORANGE This is an orange fruit and also, yes, sweet"
```

There, I've basically matched APPLE, ORANGE, and BANANA and replaced them with MYSPLITAPPLE and so on, giving me a new delimiter (MYSPLIT) on which to split the string.

Comment: Excellent, thanks! I've never seen 'sprintf' before--what does it do, exactly?

Comment: @daanoo, it's like a convenient way to sort of use placeholders (`%s`, for example) to be replaced by a different value (in this case, the collapsed values from the "fruits" vector). You can do the same with `paste`, but it's not as convenient as `sprintf` is in these types of cases.

Answer (score 2):

You could use regex `lookarounds`

```
 strsplit(string, sprintf('\\s+(?=%s)',
            paste(fruits, collapse='|')), perl=TRUE)[[1]]
 #[1] "This is a list of fruits and their properties."     
 #[2] "APPLE This is a red fruit, typically very SWEET!"   
 #[3] "BANANA This is a yellow fruit, also sweet!"         
 #[4] "ORANGE This is an orange fruit and also, yes, sweet"
```

Comment: The non-lazy approach :-) +1

Comment: @AnandaMahto  I think your approach may be faster